# Old links to beta in some question/answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, migration

I noticed on [Why are vi and Emacs popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809) that there is an link that points to beta. Though as that domain isn't available any more, I would suggests a database edit to change all links that is pointing to beta.stackoverflow.com, to point to stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: yea it could be a one time search and replace.. sure we could do it manually but Id' think this would be simple for Jeff to do

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the beta. from DNS the other day; I figured it's been almost two years (tempus fugit!) since [the start of our public beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/) so we should have moved on from any old links by then.

edit: I replaced all instances of beta.stackoverflow.com with stackoverflow.com so this shouldn't be a problem any more -- 2,506 posts had that content (some may have been deleted posts though).

Answer (score 0):

Why not permanently redirect from beta.stackoverflow.com/* to stackoverflow.com/*?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802/how-do-you-do-version-a-web-application/30168#30168) is another post pointing to beta